# Is $f(z) = Arg(z)$ Holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, determine whether $f(z) = arg(z)$ is holomorphic or not.

I understand that we can use the theorem $f(z)$ satisfies the CRE over $\mathbb{C}$ (ie. $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}= \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$ and$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = -\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}$) where $u(x,y) = Re(z)$ and $v(x,y) = Im(z)$ if and only if f(z) is holomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$.

But i'm struggling to find a way to write $f(z)$ where I have a $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ to work with.

Comment: Maybe answering this question helps: what is the imaginary part of $\mathop{\rm Arg} z$?

Comment: Neither a purely-real function nor a purely-imaginary one, other than a constant, can be analytic.  Alternatively, note that $\text{arctan2}(y,x)=\text{artan2}\left(\frac{1}{2i}(z-\bar z),\frac12(z+\bar z)\right)$ and therefore $$\frac{\partial f(z,\bar z)}{\partial \bar z}\ne 0$$So, $f$ does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: To the OP : For positive real $x,y$ the principal branch of $\arg (x+i y)$ is $\arctan y/x.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not so difficult to write down the expression of $u$ and $v$ for $f(z) = \arg z$; for instance, $v = 0$ since $f(z) = \arg z$ takes only real values.

At this point it is convenient to try to prove a general fact about non constant real function of complex variable: they never satisfy the CS equation. So any time you have a function $f: \mathbb C \mapsto \mathbb R$, and it's not constant, then CS are not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

The principal argument is not continuous on $(-\infty,0)$ hence it is not holormorphic since holomorphy implies continuity.

To prove that, consider $r \in (-\infty,0)$ and compute the following limits $$\lim_{z \to r, \Im(z) >0} arg(z)$$ and $$\lim_{z \to r, \Im(z) <0} arg(z).$$